# Unbind custom function from element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
    $( window ).resize(function() {
        if (matchMedia('only screen and (min-width: 992px)').matches) {
            $('#second').parallax();
            $('.sketches-1').parallax();
            $('#fifth').parallaxfifth();
        }
        else{
            //...
        }
   });
```

I wish to remove the parallax function on mobile devices, but how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
var parallax = function() {
    if (matchMedia('only screen and (min-width: 992px)').matches) {
        $('#second').parallax();
        $('.sketches-1').parallax();
        $('#fifth').parallaxfifth();
    }
    else{
        //...
    }
};
$(window).resize(parallax); 
//Some code here...
$(window).off('resize', parallax);
```

If you don't want to use this effect on mobile simply use:

```
function isMobile() {
  /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
}

if (!isMobile()) {
  $(window).resize(parallax); 
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to unbind only the parallax function when mobile, but bind it again if I'm not mobile, can I get this with your code? I was hoping I could do this on the else

Comment: If it is mobile don't bind, why you should unbind?

Comment: I'm trying to test some functionality and it involves resizing my window, if I do that, I will have parallax function on mobile too (if I resize a couple times), which I can't afford. (btw I can't reload)

Comment: Don't reload. In my answer above there are two solutions. Just use `off` as in the example in the answer :-).